# Animation script for my mobs are not working

Tags: lua, roblox

Im making a tower defense game and im trying to give my enemies animations. I made a basic animation for all my mobs just for testing but it doesnt work and it doesnt give any error messages. When i made the animation i set the priority to movement and i put an animator in all of my enemies humanoids and made the script. Also additional information, the script is a local script and its in starterplayerscripts.

```
local function animatemob(object)
    local Humanoid = object:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
    local animationsFolder = object:WaitForChild("Anims")
    
    if Humanoid and animationsFolder then
        local walkAnimation = animationsFolder:WaitForChild("Movement")
        if walkAnimation then
            local animator = Humanoid:FindFirstChild("Animator") or Instance.new("Animator", Humanoid)
            local walktrack = animator:LoadAnimation(walkAnimation)
            walktrack:Play()
        end
    else 
        warn("No humanoid/animatior folder for", object.Name )
    end
end

workspace.Mobs.ChildAdded:Connect(animatemob)
```

I expected the animation to work but instead all of my enemies didnt have any animations what so ever and the output bar didnt even give any error messages.

Comment: So the video i was using was actually pretty old and the animation script shouldnt have been a local script or in starterplayer scripts. what i did was to copy the script into a normal script in serverscript service. Hopefully this helps someone else in the future.